# Filter pandas dataframe based on values in multiple columns

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, pandas

I have a dataframe which has 472 columns. Of those 99 columns are dxpoa1, dxpoa2,...,dxpoa99. I want to filter out row(s) of dataframe in which dxpoa columns' values are either 7 or N or BLANK only. dxpoa's can have many values like Y, W,E,1, 7, N etc. Or they remain BLANK. Only those rows in which dxpoa's have either only 7 or N should be filtered out from data frame.
Dataset is huge having many hundred thousands rows. Therefore an efficient method will be appreciated.

```
    a  b  c dxpoa1 dxpoa2 dxpoa3 dxpoa4
0   0  A  X      W      N      X       
1   Z  W  2      7      7             
2   7  W  N      W      W      1      Z
3   1  7  E      N      N      N      N
4   Y     0      W      N      X      1
5   N  X  1      E      1      Z      7
6   1  X  7      0      A      W      A
7   X  X  Z      X      N      A      1
8   7  1  A      N      X      Z      N
9   N  A  Z      N      N      N
10  A  N  Z      7      0      A      E
11  E  N  A      Z      N      N      1
12  E  A  1      Z      E      E      W
13  N  W  Z      E      X      A      0
14  Y  1  A      W      A      E      X
```

I want row number 1, 3, 9 removed from dataframe.

I have tried many ways like:

```
df_col = [list of dxpoa column names]
df1 = df[df_col].isin(["Y", "W", "1", "E"]).values
```

It does not filter out.

Comment: Do you want to remove rows for which *any* of the dxpoa columns contain `'7'` or `'N'` or do you want to remove only those rows for which *all* of those columns contain `'7'` or `'N'`?

Comment: I want to remove only those rows for which some or all of those columns may contain '7' or 'N'. If Rows have a mix of 7,N, E, W etc or other than 7, N then I want to keep those rows. In the first line I wrote 'some' since it is not necessary that all dxpoa columns will have values. Many columns are blanks also. These columns are placeholders for values. In some rows only 1 or 2 will have values whereas in some all dxpoa will have values.

Comment: It is better to think of blanks as empty strings, `''` -- a value just like `'7'` or `'N'`. Then you can express the problem as one of removing rows for which *all* the values (in the dxpoa columns) are in `['7', 'N', '']`.

Comment: I updated dataframe supplied by you with exact scenario. I want row 1, 3, 9 removed from dataframe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

you can replace empty strings with `NaN`, `7` or `N` and then use `isin`:

```
In [196]: df[~df[cols].replace('',np.nan).isin(['7','N', np.nan]).all(axis=1)]
Out[196]:
    a  b  c dxpoa1 dxpoa2 dxpoa3 dxpoa4
0   0  A  X      W      N      X
2   7  W  N      W      W      1      Z
4   Y  0  W      N      X      1
5   N  X  1      E      1      Z      7
6   1  X  7      0      A      W      A
7   X  X  Z      X      N      A      1
8   7  1  A      N      X      Z      N
10  A  N  Z      7      0      A      E
11  E  N  A      Z      N      N      1
12  E  A  1      Z      E      E      W
13  N  W  Z      E      X      A      0
14  Y  1  A      W      A      E      X
```

**OLD answer:**

show those containing `7` or `N`

```
In [197]: df.loc[df[cols].isin(['7','N']).any(axis=1)]
Out[197]:
    a  b  c dxpoa1 dxpoa2 dxpoa3 dxpoa4
0   0  A  X      W      N      X
1   Z  W  2      7      7
3   1  7  E      N      N      N      N
4   Y  0  W      N      X      1
5   N  X  1      E      1      Z      7
7   X  X  Z      X      N      A      1
8   7  1  A      N      X      Z      N
9   N  A  Z      N      N      N
10  A  N  Z      7      0      A      E
11  E  N  A      Z      N      N      1
```

remove those containing `7` or `N`

```
In [198]: df.loc[~df[cols].isin(['7','N']).any(axis=1)]
Out[198]:
    a  b  c dxpoa1 dxpoa2 dxpoa3 dxpoa4
2   7  W  N      W      W      1      Z
6   1  X  7      0      A      W      A
12  E  A  1      Z      E      E      W
13  N  W  Z      E      X      A      0
14  Y  1  A      W      A      E      X
```

replace `any` to `all` if you want to have/exclude those where **all** columns should contain either `7` or `N`

setup:

```
rows = 15

s = [''] + list('YWE17N0AZX')
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice(s, size=(rows, 7)), columns=list('abc') + ['dxpoa1', 'dxpoa2', 'dxpoa3', 'dxpoa4'])

cols = df.filter(like='dxpoa').columns
```

Comment: It removes all rows where 7 or N occurs along with other values. I want only those rows where only 7 or N occurs to be removed

Comment: @Sanoj, always glad to help

Answer (score 2):

- You could use `df.filter(regex=r'^dxpoa')` to select columns whose name starts with `'dxpoa'`, and
- use `.isin(['7','N','']).all(axis=1)` to create a boolean mask (for the rows) which is True when *all* the values in the row are either `'7'`, `'N'`, or the empty string, `''`:

---

For example,

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'a': ['0','Z','7','1','Y','N','1','X','7','N','A','E','E','N','Y'],
     'b': ['A','W','W','7','','X','X','X','1','A','N','N','A','W','1'],
     'c': ['X','2','N','E','0','1','7','Z','A','Z','Z','A','1','Z','A'],
     'dxpoa1': ['W','7','W','N','W','E','0','X','N','N','7','Z','Z','E','W'],
     'dxpoa2': ['N','7','W','N','N','1','A','N','X','N','0','N','E','X','A'],
     'dxpoa3': ['X','','1','N','X','Z','W','A','Z','N','A','N','E','A','E'],
     'dxpoa4': ['','','Z','N','1','7','A','1','N','','E','1','W','0','X']})
mask = df.filter(regex=r'^dxpoa').isin(['7','N','']).all(axis=1)
print(df.loc[~mask])
```

yields

```
    a  b  c dxpoa1 dxpoa2 dxpoa3 dxpoa4
0   0  A  X      W      N      X       
2   7  W  N      W      W      1      Z
4   Y     0      W      N      X      1
5   N  X  1      E      1      Z      7
6   1  X  7      0      A      W      A
7   X  X  Z      X      N      A      1
8   7  1  A      N      X      Z      N
10  A  N  Z      7      0      A      E
11  E  N  A      Z      N      N      1
12  E  A  1      Z      E      E      W
13  N  W  Z      E      X      A      0
14  Y  1  A      W      A      E      X
```

Comment: This is a much more flexible solution if you have an undefined number of columns with a common name (i.e. Area_1, Area_2, Area_3,etc.). Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Use apply. If applied function returns boolean it can be used to filter rows
like in example below. Note that I didn't try to reproduce your filtering logic.

```
def analyze_row(r):
   # do whatever you want with column values here
   # return boolean: True - row stays, False - row gone
   ret = False
   if r['dpxoa1'] == 'W':
      ret = True
   return ret

filtered_df = df.ix[df.apply(analyze_row, axis = 1), :]
```